# Creating an if statement for a checkbox in an OSX app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, checkbox, preferences

I'm trying to add a working checkbox to the welcome window of my OSX app.
I have already added the checkbox to the app in Interface builder.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with writing the IF STATEMENT for a CHECKBOX in an OSX project.

I need the checkbox, which is on a welcome screen type window, to be selected when the app is opened (already done). When the checkbox is deselected by the user, when the app is run again, the welcome screen should not appear.

I have already sorted out writing to and getting the preferences, I just need to write the proper if statement and I can't quite get it right.

I do not want links to UIButton stuff (that is IOS!) and I do not want links to iPhone tutorials, etc.

I need help with OSX coding! Please! Would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cocoa bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/cocoabindings/cocoabindings.html).

Bind the value binding of the checkbox to some key on the Shared User Defaults Controller.  The logical place to store simple preferences would be `NSUserDefaults`.

[image: illustration of bindings for checkbox]

Comment: Thats all ok now with the writing to preferences, but I'm still having a little trouble wit the if statement for the checkbox :S